# How to replace all Words ending with a particular character?

Tags: python, regex

I have HTML like this

```
<b>Source:</b> <a href=\'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris\'>UCI Machine Learning Repository</a><br>Creator: <br>R.A. Fisher<br>Donor: <br>Michael Marshall (MARSHALL%<u>PLU <b>\'@\'</b> io.arc.nasa.gov</u>)<br><b>Abstract:</b>  Famous database; from Fisher, 1936<br><b>Data Set Information:</b> This is perhaps the best known database to be found in the pattern recognition literature.  Fisher\'s paper is a classic in the field and is referenced frequently to this day.  (See Duda &amp; Hart, for example.)  The data set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a type of iris plant.  One class is linearly separable from the other 2; the latter are NOT linearly separable from each other.<br>Predicted attribute: class of iris plant.<br>This is an exceedingly simple domain.<br>This data differs from the data presented in Fishers article (identified by Steve Chadwick,  <u>spchadwick <b>\'@\'</b> espeedaz.net</u> ).  The 35th sample should be: 4.9,3.1,1.5,0.2,"Iris-setosa" where the error is in the fourth feature. The 38th sample: 4.9,3.6,1.4,0.1,"Iris-setosa" where the errors are in the second and third features.  <br><b>Attribute Information:</b><br>   1. sepal length in cm<br>   2. sepal width in cm<br>   3. petal length in cm<br>   4. petal width in cm<br>   5. class: <br>      -- Iris Setosa<br>      -- Iris Versicolour<br>      -- Iris Virginica
```

I want to wrap all Words inside `<b></b>` tag which are ending with `:` (colon)

What is Regex in Python to do that?

I have tried this regex `\b(\w+:)\b` but it does not work.

Comment: try in http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

```
<b>[A-Za-z ]{1,}\:</b>
```

Fetch all these words in to a list and then do whatever processing you want to carry out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you need `<b>\w+:<\/b>`

[Try it yourself](http://pythex.org/?regex=%3Cb%3E%5Cw%2B%3A%3C%5C%2Fb%3E&test_string=%3Cb%3Ehello%3A%3C%2Fb%3E%0A%3Cb%3EHi%3C%2Fb%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = "<b>bold string with colon:</b>"

matchObj = re.match(r'<b>(.*):</b>', regex, 0)
if matchObj:
    print matchObj.group()
```